# Two TCP client application with virtual interface ip

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, network-interface

Here is my requirement.

2 TCP Client connection/Emulation from single eth port

I created two virtual interface.

```
 ifconfig eth1:0 10.0.0.2
 ifconfig eth1:1 10.0.0.3
```

Is is possible to create a TCP client code such that particular interface is used for TCP client establishment.

for example

./client_app eth1:0          - -- for client with ip 10.0.0.2

./client_app eth1:1            -- for client with ip 10.0.0.3

Comment: If your client `bind()`'s to the given ip address, it will be using "that particular interface".  If that's not the behavior you're seeing, show us your code, and show us what behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enumerate all local interfaces and get the IP address associated to these interfaces use the system call [`getifaddrs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html).

Then use the [`bind()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) system call to bind the local side of a connection to a certain local interface's IP-address.